# Trying to understand the gold-rabiner pitch detection algorithm

Tags: signal-analysis, algorithms, pitch

I am currently in the process of taking on implementing the Gold-Rabiner pitch tracking algorithm, and I came across what seemed like a good explanation of it in David Meehan's "A Code Excited Linear Predictive Coder".

However, I am a bit confused with M5, which states:  "the magnitude of the difference in amplitude between the current valley amplitude and the previous peak amplitude"--  Where M3 is depicted as the "previous peak", yet the arrow is going up to where M1 is, which is the "current peak"-- so either the instruction is wrong or the diagram is wrong-- or I am misunderstanding this entirely.

Also, a side question is, because this is talking about magnitude, this means that the arrow pointing downward at M1, is pointing at 0, correct?

[image: page from David Meehan's A Code Excited Linear Predictive Coder]

Comment: m1, m2 and m3 are all magnitudes that are calculated at a current peak. m4, m5 and m6 are all magnitudes that are calculated at the current valley (or what most people would call a negative peak). Only m1 and m4 are shown at the correct times in the diagram. m1 is the previous peak to m4, while m3 is the previous peak to m1.

Comment: Magnitudes are all absolute values (positive scalars). m1 and m4 are the only magnitudes referenced to 0. The others are referenced to other peaks / valleys as described.

Comment: this is admittedly a non-answer.  hadn't seen this question until now.  anyway i would not recommend any of these old threshold-crossing (of which zero-crossing is a subset) algs for robust pitch detection.  i would begin with autocorrelation or AMDF or ASDF data and then the brains are at picking (and sticking with) the right peak indicating high correlation.